# mingw32-make undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)' OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, reference, undefined

So I have OpenCV libraries downloaded from here 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/3.4.6/opencv-3.4.6-vc14_vc15.exe/download

CMake gui with cmakelist.txt like this

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
>
> project(Display)
>
> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
>
> message(STATUS "OpenCV library
>   status:") message(STATUS "    config:
>   ${OpenCV_DIR}") message(STATUS "
>   version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
>   message(STATUS "    libraries:
>   ${OpenCV_LIBS}") message(STATUS "
>   include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
>
> add_executable(Display
>   DisplayImage.cpp)
>
> target_link_libraries(Display
>   ${OpenCV_LIBS})

and have a simple cpp like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    // cout << "You have entered " << argc 
 //         << " arguments:" << "\n";

 //        for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) 
 //         cout << argv[i] << "\n"; 

 //        cout << "a" << argv[1];
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

already configure it with cmake-gui and this shows up

> OpenCV library status:
>       config: D:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib
>       version: 3.4.6
>       libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_world
>       include path: D:/opencv/build/include;D:/opencv/build/include/opencv;D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2
>   Configuring done Generating done

seems good right ? and then on the build directory from command prompt, i typed `mingw32-make`
and this shows up

> CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x72):
>   undefined reference to
>   `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0xe3):
>   undefined reference to`
>   cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&,
>   int)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x129):
>   undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(cv::String const&,
>   cv::_InputArray const&)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x149):
>   undefined reference to`
>   cv::waitKey(int)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc[__ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc]+0x42):
>   undefined reference to
>   `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev[__ZN2cv6StringD1Ev]+0xf):
>   undefined reference to`
>   cv::String::deallocate()'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$*ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0*[__ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x1c):
>   undefined reference to
>   `cv::String::deallocate()'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to`
>   cv::fastFree(void*)'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[__ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x40):
>   undefined reference to
>   `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
>   CMakeFiles\Display.dir/objects.a(DisplayImage.cpp.obj):DisplayImage.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MataSEOS0_[__ZN2cv3MataSEOS0_]+0xb4):
>   undefined reference to`
>   cv::fastFree(void*)' collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   mingw32-make[2]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles\Display.dir\build.make:104:
>   Display.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make[1]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/Display.dir/all] Error 2
>   mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:83: all]
>   Error 2

how do i fix this ? or is it because that i use the library straight from the website ? 
i also try something like putting a wrong parameter on the `imread` function and then type `mingw32-make` and it did tell me that i use a wrong parameter. If they know i used the wrong parameter, then why they can't tell what is `imread` for (or why is it undefined reference ? ) ? I'm using windows.

I'm very new to these libraries, mingw, and cmake, so i'm sorry if my question is stupid.

this question is not duplicate because, i use windows and mingw32-make, everyone that asks this question did not use that and the question is in a different situation than mine.

Comment: @SergeyA: Duplicate "What is an undefined reference..." is suited for questions where an asker **don't know** what is a *linking*. That duplicate isn't suited for the given question because the code shown **definitely performs linking** (`target_link_libraries`) and the asker also explicitely checks list of linked libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not so obvious, but for format a code and an error log it is better to use **code formatting**. *Blockquote* formatting is not good for this purpose, because it **loses** original **newlines**, making the code/log to be harder understandable. Please, re-paste `CMakeLists.txt` code and the error log, and format them as a *code* (`Ctrl+K` or `{}` button). Other parts of your question seems good.